# PostgreSQL TRIGGER - how to find out if we are running IMMEDIATE or DEFERRED?

Tags: postgresql, triggers, plpgsql

Assume we have a trigger

```sql
CREATE CONSTRAINT TRIGGER test
    AFTER UPDATE OF name
    ON public.test
    DEFERRABLE INITIALLY IMMEDIATE
    FOR EACH ROW
EXECUTE FUNCTION public.test_trigger();
```

Now, this trigger could be executed IMMEDIATE - or DEFERRED, if `SET CONSTRAINTS ... DEFERRED` would have been called.

Can I find out from within the trigger if it is currently running as IMMEDIATE or DEFERRED?

Comment: I checked source code, and I think so this information is not available.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you cannot. I checked postgres's source code, and this is only private information.